# Match multiple param in Route with React Router Dom in WordPress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-router-dom

I want to pass multiple params to my route and show components accordingly. My URLs are

```
http://localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wptest

http://localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wptest&path=home

http://localhost:3000/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wptest&path=settings
```

I am using "react-router-dom" version 5.2.0

How to pass multiple params to my route and show components accordingly. I'm not sure about query param.

What is the best way to chive this?

```
<Route path="/wp-admin/admin.php">   
    <WpTest/>
</Route>
<Route path="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wptest&path=home">   
    <Home />
</Route>
<Route path="/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wptest&path=settings">   
    <Settings />
</Route>
```

I can match `/wp-admin/admin.php` in the 1st route. But I am not able to match `?page=wptest&path=home` this part in Route.